# I wonder why it does not work at IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I wonder why it does not work at IE8.
In IE9 and above, everything works fine. I wonder why this is happening.
Perhaps I think it's because JavaScript uses code that does not support ie8.

```
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Home', this, 'red')">Home</button>


<div id="Home" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Home</h3>
  <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
</div>

<script>
function openPage(pageName,elmnt,color) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
    }
    document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";
    elmnt.style.backgroundColor = color;

}
// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>
```

----link : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_full_page_tabs

Comment: There are only two functions you're calling. `getElementById()` and `getElementsByClassName()`. A short search with "IE8 <function name>" should give you really fast an answer on your problem.

Comment: I did not know it was a beginner in JavaScript. Thanks to you.

Comment: A well-meaning advice: forget about IE8 ;)

Comment: I got a chance because of you. Thank you for letting me know how to catch fish. This has been fixed using the querySelectorAll (.' ') Method. Korea still wants to support IE8 or higher. Thank you!

Comment: @Amerimnos You might [want to post your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) with the solution

Comment: @Bergi Oh! This site is the first post today. So I am awkward. Thank you for the good information.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed using the querySelectorAll ('. ') Method. I think querySelectorAll ('.tablink ') and getElementsByClassName("tablink") are almost the same. Korea still wants to support IE8 or higher.

```js
function openPage(pageName,elmnt,color) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.querySelectorAll(".tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.querySelectorAll(".tablink");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
    }
    document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";
    elmnt.style.backgroundColor = color;

}
// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
/* Style tab links */
.tablink {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    font-size: 17px;
    width: 25%;
}

.tablink:hover {
    background-color: #777;
}

/* Style the tab content (and add height:100% for full page content) */
.tabcontent {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    display: none;
    padding: 100px 20px;
    height: 100%;
}

#hacsul {background-color:white;}
#News {background-color:white;}
#Contact {background-color:white;}
#About {background-color:white;}
#t3 {background-color:white;}
```

```html
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('hacsul', this, 'orange')">hacsul</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('News', this, 'orange')" id="defaultOpen">News</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Contact', this, 'orange')">Contact</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('About', this, 'orange')">About</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('t3', this, 'orange')">t3</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('t3', this, 'orange')">t5</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('t3', this, 'orange')">t6</button>



<div id="hacsul" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>hacsul</h3>
  <p>hacsul is where the heart is..</p>
</div>

<div id="News" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>News</h3>
  <p>Some news this fine day!</p> 
</div>

<div id="Contact" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Contact</h3>
  <p>Get in touch, or swing by for a cup of coffee.</p>
</div>

<div id="About" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>About</h3>
  <p>Who we are and what we do.</p>
</div>

<div id="t3" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>t3</h3>
    <p>Who we are and what we do.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="t4" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>About</h3>
    <p>Who we are and what we do.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="t5" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>About</h3>
    <p>Who we are and what we do.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="t6" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>About</h3>
    <p>Who we are and what we do.</p>
  </div>
```